# Is there a material with non-monotone density dependence on pressure?

Tags: pressure, density, material-science

Is there a material with such non-linear effects (including chemical reactions, phase transitions etc ...) so that there would be range where pressure increase would yield density decrease?

What would be the answer if we consider volume instead of density?

Comment: A good question but remember that non-monotonic and non-linear are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I find odd that this quite old question did not receive an answer.

$$
\left. \frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{V}} \right|_{T,N}=
\left. -\frac{\rho}{V}\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{\rho}} \right|_{T}
$$
Such identity implies that if $P$  is an increasing (decreasing) function of the density $\rho$, it should also be a decreasing (increasing) function of the volume $V$.

The sign of $\left. \frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{V}} \right|_{T,N}$ for a homogeneous thermodynamic system must be negative, according to the convexity of the Helmholtz free energy with respect to the volume. Convexity which, in turn, is equivalent to the thermodynamic stability of the phase.